# List access rules for other users?

Tags: gitolite

With this command:

```
ssh git@<my git server>
```

I can get a nice listing of my access privileges, i.e.

```
  @R  @W   some_branch
  @R       some_other_branch
```

Is there a way I can get a similar listing for another gitolite user, even if I don't have access to that user's private key?

Comment: I've learned that `ssh git@<git server> info <repo> <username>` will list _per repository_ access rules; still looking for a way to get a _per branch_ listing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to modify the [`src/commands/info`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/commands/info) file, in order to get the output you want.

That `ssh git@server info` command only takes a `<repo name pattern>` as an argument.